# Warning: Unsuccessful read: Matching failure in format

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am having issues reading data from a serial port.

Most of the time, the code works and I am able to successfully read in 1000 data points for both `z` and `y`.

Sometimes, no data is read from the serial port, and sometimes only 40 data points are read from the serial port rather than the expected 1000. I receive this warning when performing the read.

> Warning: Unsuccessful read: Matching failure in format.. Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

What does this warning mean and how can I change the code below to prevent it.

```
clk
clear all
delete(instrfindall);
b = serial('COM2','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(b);
k = 1;
n = 0;
while(n < 1000)
    z(k) = fscanf(b, '%d');
    y(k) = fscanf(b, '%d');
    n = n + 1;
    k = k + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the problem is timing. The error message indicates that the serial port did not receive as many bytes as it required to create a value with the format you specified before it timed out. For simple examples, the code you have works fine, but as you discovered, it is not robust.

You have to know two things before you start:

1. Does your serial device send data in "lines", using a line
   terminator character, or not?
2. How many bytes do you expect to
   read each time you read data from the serial port?

Then there are two approaches:

A) Procedural Wait (easier, less robust): Add a statement in your code which waits until a certain number of bytes have been received, and then reads them.

```
numBytes = 10; % read this many bytes when ready
% make sure serial object input buffer is large enough
serialport = serial('COM100','InputBufferSize',numbytes*10);

fopen(serialport);

while 1
    ba = serialport.BytesAvailable;
    if ba > numBytes
        mydata = fread(serialport, numBytes);
        % do whatever with mydata
    end
    drawnow;
end

fclose(serialport);
```

B) Object Callback (more advanced/complex, potentially more robust): Defined a callback function which is executed whenever a certain condition is met. The callback function handles the data from the serial device. The execute condition is either:

- a) a certain number of bytes has been received
- b) a line terminator
  character has been received

The following example uses condition a). It requires two functions, one for your main program and one for the callback.

```
function useserialdata
% this function is your main program

numBytes = 10; % read this many bytes when ready
% make sure serial object input buffer is large enough
serialport = serial('COM100','InputBufferSize',numbytes*10);

% assign the callback function to the serial port object
serialport.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
serialport.BytesAvailableFcnCount = numBytes;
serialport.BytesAvailableFcn = {@getmydata,numBytes};
serialport.UserData.isnew = 0;

fopen(serialport);

while 1
    if serialport.UserData.isnew > 0
        newdata=ar.UserData.newdata; % get the data from the serial port
        serialport.UserData.isnew=0; % indicate that data has been read

        % use newdata for whatever

    end
end

fclose(serialport);


function getmydata(obj,event,numBytes)
% this function is called when bytes are ready at the serial port

mydata = fread(obj, numBytes);
% return the data for plotting/processing
if obj.UserData.isnew==0
    obj.UserData.isnew=1; % indicate that we have new data
    obj.UserData.newdata = mydata;
else
    obj.UserData.newdata=[obj.UserData.newdata; mydata];
end
```

Obviously these are toy examples, and you will have many other details like timeouts, error handling, program responsiveness, etc to consider, depending on the details of how the serial device works. See the matlab help file for "Serial Port Object Properties" for more information.